# BASH - Trap Ctrl+C to clean process before quiting

Tags: bash, kill-process

I want to trap <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> in my script so that I can do some cleaning before I quit the script. I have this so far:

```
trap ctrl_c INT

main_script() {
   #State of the art technology happening here
}

ctrl_c() {
   #Do some cleaning
   exit 1
}
```

The problem is that after I press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and get back to console, The console behaves abnormally. I cannot see my keyboard entries anymore and pressing enter doesn't go to a new line. For example, this is what my console looks like:

> root@ZonkedCream:~# root@ZonkedCream:~# root@ZonkedCream:~#

Help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We don't have the source code of your script so... Just guessing.

Probably you script changes stty settings somehow and they were not restored when you break the application with CTRL-C.

I'd suggest you to save your stty flags as soon as your script starts and restore them in your ctrl_c() function or - at least - use `stty sane` in ctrl_c() before quitting.